# Is this metric space complete: $d(f,g)=\max\limits_{t\in[0,1]} |f(t)-g(t)|$ for $C^1$-functions?

Tags: metric-spaces, complete-spaces

> The space $\mathcal C^1[0,1]$ with the metric $$d(f,g)=\max_{t\in[0,1]} |f(t)-g(t)|$$

No, it is not complete metric space: by Stone-Weierstrass thm we know that $|x|$ can be uniformly approximated by sequence of polynomials which are clearly $\mathcal{C}^1[0,1]$, but $|x|$ is not $\mathcal{C}^1$.
Is my argument correct?

Comment: As Pete points out in his answer the *idea* can be made into an argument (although I myself wouldn't apply Stone-Weierstrass, that's quite an overkill for this question). However, you should pick another function, e.g. $x \mapsto |x-1/2|$ (which you *can* approximate uniformly by *explicit polynomials* -- how?) Note that the function $|x| = x$ on $[0,1]$ *is* $C^1$.

Comment: Note that, uniform convergence preserves continuity, but it does not preserve differentiability.

Comment: so my argument is incorrect in $[0,1]$ :( but I dont know how to prove the result Mr. Pete has written in his answer

Comment: @Patience: Switching from $|x|$ to (say) $|x-\frac{1}{2}|$ seems like a very minor adjustment.  Is there something else in my answer that you don't understand?

Comment: how to show $C[0,1]$ is dense in $C^1[0,1]$?

Comment: @Patience: Rather $C^1[0,1]$ is dense in $C[0,1]$.  As you say, by Weierstrass Approximation, the subspace $\mathcal{P}[0,1]$ of $C[0,1]$ is dense.  Since $\mathcal{P}[0,1] \subset C^1[0,1] \subset C[0,1]$, also $C^1[0,1]$ is dense.

Comment: ohh thank you for the help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**Added**: By $C[0,1]$ I mean the set of continuous functions $f: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ endowed with the metric $d(f,g) = \max_{x \in [0,1]} |f(x)-g(x)|$.  This is a complete metric space by the Cauchy Criterion for Uniform Convergence.]

Yes.  To recap it: you have a complete metric space, $\mathcal{C}[0,1]$, and a subspace, $\mathcal{C}^1[0,1]$, which is not closed (rather, it is proper and dense).  Therefore $\mathcal{C}^1[0,1]$ cannot be complete.

**Added**: As t.b. points out, the absolute value function *is* $C^1$ on the interval $[0,1]$, so you should pick something else (e.g. what t.b. says).  I also agree that Weierstrass Approximation is much more than you need here.  For instance, in Example 7 of [these notes](https://web.archive.org/web/20130728123305/http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/243functions1.pdf) I show -- in an intentionally clunky, hands-on fashion -- that the absolute value function is a uniform limit of $C^1$-functions on $[-1,1]$.

Comment: AFAICT the notes linked in the answer are now part of Pete L. Clark's text [Honors Calculus](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/~pete/2400full.pdf) ([Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20220503044808/http://alpha.math.uga.edu/~pete/2400full.pdf)).